# Trying to use Bamboo and MSDeploy

Tags: msdeploy, bamboo

I have a builder in Bamboo that I've created pointing to MSDeploy executable.
I want to take a backup of the current web site before I deploy the new one.

Here is the command line that I'd run:
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:contentPath="Default Web Site\MyService",computerName="myserver" -dest:package="MyService_backup_before_43.zip" -enableLink:AppPoolExtension

So I've setup a new MSDeploy builder to point to "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe"
And then I choose my builder to be MSDeploy.

And the argument is:
-verb:sync -source:contentPath="Default Web Site\MyService",computerName="myserver" -dest:package="MyService_backup_before_43.zip" -enableLink:AppPoolExtension

However MSDeploy keeps complaining that:
Unrecognized argument '"-source:contentPath="Default'. All arguments must begin with "-".

Bamboo messes about with the argument line obviously to try and be smart. However I need it to keep the double quotes (") where they are.

I've tried every combination of single and double quotes I can think of, i.e. in front of all the arguments, in front of only the ones that have spaces, or only the ones that have quotes.

Anyone know how to get this to work please?

Comment: You have to type as a single liner in the command line.  How are you typing in the command line?

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem and didn't find the solution, did you?

As a **workaround** you can get rid of spaces in your source. You should change

```
"Default Web Site\MyService"
```

to

```
"DefaultWebSite\MyService"
```